# Should I go back and reflag questions/answers that aged away?

Tags: discussion, flags, aged-away

I was going back through my flagging history, and I noticed several flags that had aged away. I looked back at the questions/answers, and found that several of them still had the potential to be flagged (i.e. the flag had merit), but it just got buried.

Is going back and reflagging these older items (say a few months old to even years old) frowned on, or is it a legitimate cleanup procedure? These questions are long buried, but they still exist in the system. Do moderators want these gone or is it enough that they are buried?

This is partially a selfish question, as I am trying for the Marshal badge on SO, but I don't want to do this in an illegitimate fashion.

Your thoughts?

Edit:

I saw this related question: [Is there a time limit, to how far back answers/questions should be flagged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77979/is-there-a-time-limit-to-how-far-back-answers-questions-should-be-flagged?rq=1)

However, in this case, there was an original flag that aged away, so is the aging away considered an action that was taken (i.e. not enough attention = shouldn't be deleted/closed/etc)?

Comment: Well, since flags only started aging away rather recently, it can't be *too* discouraged, right?

Comment: Related: [Age close votes after 14 days, regardless of views, allowing recasting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250223/578924) (in-depth of how and why close flags / votes worked over time and now)

Answer (score 4):

Since the flag aged away, I would say it is legitimate to reflag the post, but I would expect it to age away again.
I would rather flag more recent posts, and re-flag old posts if they are really bad. I am not sure about suggesting to try a flag for moderation attention; I feel it is more important for moderators to pay attention to more recent posts, but I can understand there could be old posts that could be used as excuse to ask bad questions (for example).